# How do I get data from Multiple dropdown select boxes to send a jquery ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form with 2 Select Boxes that we will call Input Box 1 and Input Box 2. I am using the onChange event when a selection is made in Input Box 1 to call a script that should get some data from Input Box 1 and Input Box 2 to send via Ajax to a script that will return a third Select Box in a specified div with filtered values from a database. I have most of it worked out but I am having problems getting the data I need out of the on page Input Select Boxes. An image of the area of the form for a visual aid is pictured below:

[image: Select Boxes Form]

This is the code I have for the html form portion:

```
<div id="Input_Div_1">
<select name="Input_Box_1" id="Input_Box_1" onchange="sendthedatatotheajax(this);">
<option value="1" data-image="image1.jpg" data-extra1="a">Apple</option>
<option value="2" data-image="image2.jpg" data-extra1="b">Banana</option>
<option value="3" data-image="image3.jpg" data-extra1="c">Orange</option>
<option value="4" data-image="image4.jpg" data-extra1="d">Grapes</option>
</select>
</div>

<div id="Input_Div_2">
<select name="Input_Box_2" id="Input_Box_2">
<option value="1" data-image="image_cat.jpg" data-extra1="x">Red</option>
<option value="2" data-image="image_dog.jpg" data-extra1="y">Blue</option>
<option value="3" data-image="image_pig.jpg" data-extra1="z">Green</option>
<option value="4" data-image="image_wolf.jpg" data-extra1="qq">Cyan</option>
</select>
</div>

<div id="Output_Div_1">
<select name="Output_Box_1" id="Output_Box_1">
<option value="1" data-image="image_usa.jpg" data-extra1="washington">Waiting for Data 1</option>
<option value="2" data-image="image_russia.jpg" data-extra1="moscow">Waiting for Data 2</option>
</select>
</div>
```

This is the Javascript that I have so far that needs some help to send the data to a php script that will return the third select Output box.

```
<script>
function sendthedatatotheajax(sel) {
    var the_Input_Box_1_value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;

// This is where I Need Help Start
    var the_Input_Box_1_dataextra1 = [how.do.i.get.this.value?].value;
    var the_Input_Box_2_value = [again.how.do.i.get.this.value?].value;
// This is where I Need Help Stop

    $("#Output_Div_1").html( "" );
    if (the_Input_Box_1_value.length > 0 ) { 

     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "sendbackthedata.php",
            data: {"inputbox1value": the_Input_Box_1_value, "inputbox1dataextra1": the_Input_Box_1_dataextra1, "inputbox2value": the_Input_Box_2_value},
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function () { 
                $('#Output_Div_1').html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="" width="24" height="24">');
            },
            success: function(html) {    
                $("#Output_Div_1").html( html );
            }
        });
    } 
}
</script>
```

My question is what code do I use to get the following

1) The "value" of Input-Box-1
2) The "data-extra1" of Input-Box-1
3) The "value of Input-Box-2.

Any help with this would be much appreciated... Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Answers to your questions,

1. The "value" of Input-Box-1 : **sel.value;**
2. The "data-extra1" of Input-Box-1 : **$('#Input_Box_2').find(':selected').attr('data-extra1');**
3. The "value of Input-Box-2 : **$('#Output_Box_1').value();**

Those will work hopefully

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, then you can do as following example:

```
$("#Input_Box_2 option:selected").val()
```

So you'll be getting the value of the selected option, if you want to find any attribute, you need to look for it with `attr()`, so it would be like:

```
$("#Input_Box_2 option:selected").attr("data-extra1")
```